# Getting handle information with MiniDump causes ArgumentException

Tags: c#, exception, handle, minidump

I am trying to get minidump information about handles of some process. 
I am getting a List of handles of type `MINIDUMP_HANDLE_DESCRIPTOR_2` and I am trying to read the info about the handle which I can access with `ObjectInfoRva`.

However, I always get this exception:

> System.ArgumentException occurred   HResult=-2147024809   Message=Not
>   enough space available in the buffer.   Source=mscorlib

That's my method

```
public unsafe DbgHelp.MINIDUMP_HANDLE_OBJECT_INFORMATION ReadInfo(uint rva)
{
    try
    {
        DbgHelp.MINIDUMP_HANDLE_OBJECT_INFORMATION result = default(DbgHelp.MINIDUMP_HANDLE_OBJECT_INFORMATION);
        byte* baseOfView = null;
        _safeMemoryMappedViewHandle.AcquirePointer(ref baseOfView);

        IntPtr position = new IntPtr(baseOfView + rva);

        result = _safeMemoryMappedViewHandle.Read<DbgHelp.MINIDUMP_HANDLE_OBJECT_INFORMATION>((ulong)position);
        return result;
    }
    finally
    {
        _safeMemoryMappedViewHandle.ReleasePointer();
    }
}
```

`MINIDUMP_HANDLE_DESCRIPTOR_2` declaration:

```
 public struct MINIDUMP_HANDLE_DESCRIPTOR_2
{
    public UInt64 Handle;
    public uint TypeNameRva;
    public uint ObjectNameRva;
    public UInt32 Attributes;
    public UInt32 GrantedAccess;
    public UInt32 HandleCount;
    public UInt32 PointerCount;
    public uint ObjectInfoRva;
    public UInt32 Reserved0;
}
```

The `_safeMemoryMappedViewHandle` is initialized - that's how I've got the handles list in the first place.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Micro-optimizing this code does not help you get it right, very little reason to avoid just a plain FileStream.  You are probably not walking the MINIDUMP_DIRECTORY correctly and got an invalid RVA.  The difference between a 32-bit and a 64-bit minidump might be one reason.  Or got a plain MINIDUMP_HANDLE_DESCRIPTOR, not the extended version, so bomb on the non-existing ObjectInfoRva.  Impossible to tell from the snippet.  Add more Debug.Assert() so you can catch a bad RVA before it turns into a hard-to-diagnose exception.

Comment: How can I know that the rva that I get is a bad one? Currently I am working on x86 only...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the baseOfView pointer - I didn't calculated it right. I needed the set the offset accordingly to the base stream address...

Here is a version of `ReadInfo` function which worked for me eventually:

```
public unsafe DbgHelp.MINIDUMP_HANDLE_OBJECT_INFORMATION ReadInfo(uint rva, IntPtr streamPtr)
{
    DbgHelp.MINIDUMP_HANDLE_OBJECT_INFORMATION result = new DbgHelp.MINIDUMP_HANDLE_OBJECT_INFORMATION();

    try
    {
        byte* baseOfView = null;
        _safeMemoryMappedViewHandle.AcquirePointer(ref baseOfView);
        ulong offset = (ulong)streamPtr - (ulong)baseOfView;
        result = _safeMemoryMappedViewHandle.Read<DbgHelp.MINIDUMP_HANDLE_OBJECT_INFORMATION>(offset);
    }
    finally
    {
        _safeMemoryMappedViewHandle.ReleasePointer();
    }

    return result;
}
```